# ¿como eliminar a usuarios de phpmyadmin ya subidos al dominio?

Tags: phpmyadmin

me da este error y de veras quiero probar eliminar datos como usuarios y demas [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te dice que no puedes borrar el registro porque hay otra tabla que tiene un registro que hace referencia a el

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El mensaje de error que te devuelve dice que no puedes eliminar ese usuario porque existe una foreing key en otra tabla (CART), que lo impide. Es decir que tienes una dependencia de FK donde ese usuario aparece al menos en un registro.
Lo que tienes que resolver es la lógica de negocio que quieres aplicar: Si quieres eliminar un usuario, ¿pueden eliminarse también todos los registros relacionados con ese mismo usuario en otras tablas?

Esto es algo de análisis de sistemas, no hay código para compartirte. Es una definición que tienes que hacer para **la aplicación que vas a usar con esta base**.

La solución **usual** es sencilla: No es conveniente eliminar datos base como los de usuarios. Lo que se hace es desactivarlos con un borrado lógico, donde usas al menos un campo "fecha_baja" nulable, que sólo llenas cuando lo quieres quitar, y además **usas ese mismo campo para validar los usuarios activos y no mostrar los dados de baja** (con la ventaja adicional de sólo tener que poner de nuevo NULL en el campo para reactivarlo).

Como digo, es un tema de análisis de sistemas, no exactamente de programación.

Ahora bien, si lo que quieres en borrar ese usuario, deberás borrar previamente todos los datos de todas las tablas donde aparezca como FK, pero también tienes que tener en cuenta que si las PK de esas tablas se usan en otras tablas mas como FK, **también deberás borrar todos los registros de esas terceras tablas, y así...**

¿Se entiende el problema?

Por eso es mas sencillo desactivar los registros y no borrarlos, en especial cuando la base ya está **productiva**...